# function is not defined at html onclick and ng-click as well as ui-sref is not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, button, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to open a modal on a button click that is added dynamically to the infoWindow of a Marker on my map.

I tried several things now, like using onclick, ng-click and ui-sref. onclick is not working because it says that my function is not defined. ng-click is not firing and ui-sref for using the $state.go('someState')-method is neither.

```
var createMarkerOnMap = function (param) {

        if (param.hasOwnProperty('type')) {
            var contentString = "<h5>" + 'Social-Media-Filter ID: '+ param.id + "</h5><hr color='#000000' noshade>X Ereignisse in diesem Filter  <br>" + param.keywords;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString +
                '<br><button id="detailsButtonFilter" ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"></i> Details</button>' +
                ' <button id= "editButtonFilter" ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></i> Bearbeiten</button>'
            });

            // document.getElementById ("detailsButtonFilter").addEventListener ("click", bla, false);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(param.latitude, param.longitude),
                title: param.keywords,
                icon: getSocialMediaIcon(param.type)
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });

        } else {
            var contentString = "<h5>" + param.name + "</h5><hr color='#000000' noshade> Notfallwarnung Stufe " + param.warningLevel + " aktiv <br>";
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString +
                '<br><button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"></i> Details</button> ' +
                ' <button ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></i> Bearbeiten</button>'
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(param.latitude, param.longitude),
                title: param.name,
                icon: setPdIcon(param.warningLevel)
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
        }
        return marker;
    };
```

Well...I think that my HTML that get added dynamically is not rendered correctly but I don't know how to handle it in that situation.

[image of my infoWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snF6k.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make button *clickable* inside `google.maps.InfoWindow`, `content` property needs to be compiled using `$compile` service:

```
var content = '<button ng-click="cityDetail(' + idx + ')" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"></i> Details</button>';
var compiledContent = $compile(content)($scope)

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    $scope.infowindow.setContent(compiledContent[0]);
    $scope.infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
});
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('map-example', [])
    .controller('MapController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $compile) {
        function initialize() {
            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: { lat: -38.363, lng: 131.044 }
            });

            $scope.cities = [
                { title: 'Sydney', lat: -33.873033, lng: 151.231397 },
                { title: 'Melbourne', lat: -37.812228, lng: 144.968355 }
            ];

            //create a single instance of Info  Window
            $scope.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ''
            });
            //render markers
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++) {
                createMarkerOnMap(i);
            }
        }


        var createMarkerOnMap = function (idx) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.cities[idx].lat, $scope.cities[idx].lng),
                map: $scope.map,
                title: $scope.cities[idx].title
            });
            
            var content = '<button ng-click="cityDetail(' + idx + ')" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"></i> Details</button>';
            var compiledContent = $compile(content)($scope)

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                $scope.infowindow.setContent(compiledContent[0]);
                $scope.infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });

        };

        $scope.cityDetail = function (index) {
            alert(JSON.stringify($scope.cities[index]));
        };

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    });
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 400px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="map-example" ng-controller="MapController"> 
    <div id="map"></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Works very well. Thanks for saving my time. And thanks for posting this question too. @AlexanderHölzemann.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is with the order of arguments. The event handler need to be the first parameter like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener('click', hereComesTargetEvent, function() {
  infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
});
```

Comment: this listener is just for clicking on my markers an opening an infoWindow. In this window you see 2 more buttons. For showing detail informations and editing the entity attributes. I'm going to add a picture to my initial post for a better understand. My problem are the buttons inside of this window.